# wifi networking freezes then unfreezes

Tags: wireless, ssh

I have a Mac Mini (OS X Lion) and a Thinkpad running Ubuntu 11.04. When I log into the same server from both computer via ssh, the connection the Thinkpad is extremely slow compared to the ssh connection on my Mac Mini. it even hangs and freezes, while the Mini does not. They are both on the same WiFi local network. Any suggestions on how I can diagnose the problem on the Ubuntu Thinkpad?

It seems that the ssh session starts to hang or freeze when I stop typing in it for a few seconds.

EDIT. OK it seems that my whole network connectivity freezes for seconds at a time, so I can't hit the network for anything. The it starts working again.

If I run ping yahoo.com, it pings yahoo repeatedly. But every few minutes it just freezes for 10 or more seconds. Then it starts pinging again, without registering any abnormal ping interval. During the hang nothing that hits the network responds: web browser, curl, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - try to ping some server (google.com ?) while trying to reproduce this problem. It might be a case with wireless card drivers. Also try using ethernet cable.

If the problem appears only on SSH try ssh'ing with -v parameter and paste here the output.